# Application freeze in 3rd party library call

Tags: c++, qt

I am working on a `c++` measurement software which uses [a 3rd party API](http://www.ebru.de/epcidio.htm) for the interface all sensors are connected to. This API is not open source and no debug library is available.

In some occasions, the software freezes when starting to read a value from the interface. While I could not determine what criterions cause the problem and why it only happens sometimes so far, I'd like to intercept the freezing and implement some error handling, which would also allow me to better debug the issue.

In my code, I simply have a call

```
BOOL result = false;
result = pciadioAIStartConversion(board_index, channel_nr, range);
```

where, if the error occurs, `pciadioAIStartConversion` never returns. I am looking for some simple functionality to keep the software running and return if the call takes to long.

I am using the `Qt` framework (4.8.6) so a possible solution would be using the event system and a `QTimer`, but therefore the call would need its own thread if I'm not mistaken and that seems like overkill to me.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to implement timeout other than spawning a separate thread.

Comment: You may create a separate `QProcess` that will do a call from 3rdparty library, and use `QLocalSocket` or `std::cin / std::cout` for communation. If you are not getting responce you may safely kill process. It is more safe, than terminating threads.

Comment: If your external software component freeze, it is possible that it still holds resources even when it will killed. Maybe the external devices are in an undefined state and simply restarting the thread will not help. From my experience it is not a good idea to rely on broken libraries. Workarounds with restarting software sounds terrible at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

piezol is right You need a separate thread which can be quite a mess but the good news is that Qt thread framework (which is called QtConcurrent) is really helpful.

Here is an example for running a standard function in a separate thread mantaining control of it.

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
#include <QString>
#include <qtconcurrentrun.h>
#include <QApplication>

using namespace QtConcurrent;

void hello(QString name)
{
    qDebug() << "Hello" << name << "from" << QThread::currentThread();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QFuture<void> f1 = run(hello, QString("Alice"));
    QFuture<void> f2 = run(hello, QString("Bob"));
    f1.waitForFinished();       
    f2.waitForFinished();     
}
```

Comment: This looks promising, have not used the concurrent module so far. But I can't find the `waitForFinished()` method with a given time in the documentation of `QFuture`, do I miss something of am I blind?

Comment: No you are not blind, I am, I took the documentation from the QProcess waitforFinshed instead of QFuture, looks like you will have to use a timer

Comment: `QFutureWatcher` is what you should be using. `waitForXxx` methods block the GUI.